# JMeter - Error to run shutdown.cmd when test running in Non-GUI mode

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am running the test for API Performance testing for 2000 users in CLI Mode at first. Second round of test with 5000 VUs but the second round the test won't stop. I run for for interval time of 12 minutes but past 12 minutes the test still dont finish the thread by 5000 VUs.

So I want to shutdown the test running. This error occurs when I want to stop the test running (click shutdown.cmd)

[image]

I also tried to open the mirror-server.cmd to troubleshoot:

[image]

By double clicking these exe file in the JMeter bin folder (I tried to click both but same error).
[image]

And suddenly my test is running almost 20k VUs now:
[image]

I also already restart my pc and try to run again with 500 VUs, but the number doesn't start with 500 VUs instead, it is starting with 5000 VUs!
[image]

Can advise what is the issue here? Is the root cause come from the second round which does not finished the test? Luckily I don't encounter any errors of Out of Memory at the moment. How to force stop all tests that currently running in the command? Please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. These are not `.exe` files, they are [Windows Batch scripts](https://www.howtogeek.com/263177/how-to-write-a-batch-script-on-windows/)
2. I cannot reproduce your issue using the steps you provided:

   [image]

   You can try stopping your test by running this `shutdown.cmd` from the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation from [Windows Command Prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/)

   [image]
3. You can just press `Control` + `C` in the shell window where your test is running to stop it
4. As the last resort you can always use [taskkill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill) command to terminate all Java processes

   ```
   taskkill /f /im "java.exe"
   ```

   Warning: it will terminate all Java process instances, not only JMeter
5. The number of active threads is in this column:

   [image]
6. It's hard to say why your test is not ending without seeing your test configuration and [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) preferably with [debug logging enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) for the Thread Group and Timer components you're using

Comment: Thanks sir. I checked the log file which i command from CLI Mode -j resultlogtest.csv. I tried to run 5000 VU for 30 minutes thread time but at minute 30 above, the error message "Stopping because end time detected by thread" how can I know the test already stopping since i cannot run the shutdown.cmd?

Comment: one more question, do i dont have to apply concurrency thread group here?